# Laravel Nova - Error installation tool /compiling npm

Tags: python, laravel, npm

While installing a new component, a new card or a new tool via Laravel Nova I get this error.

I tried to install Python, at the moment I have the version installed.
I tried to search on the internet and in various discussions but I could not find any answers that help me directly.

```
 Would you like to install the tool's NPM dependencies? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > y

npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node

> node-sass@4.14.1 install /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass/v4.14.1/darwin-arm64-83_binding.node
Cannot download "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass/v4.14.1/darwin-arm64-83_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bool/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> es5-ext@0.10.61 postinstall /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bool/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.19.1/bin/node /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.19.1/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.19.1 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb download using dist-url https://npm.taobao.org/dist
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/path/to/executable/python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /path/to/executable/python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/bool-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo-boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:191:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  /path/to/executable/python Error: not found: /path/to/executable/python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Bo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:191:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:191:21)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.19.1/bin/node" "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Boo/boo-landings-nova/nova-components/PriceTracker/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"14.19.1","npm":"6.14.16"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I have a Macbook pro 13" with M1.
MacOS Monterey Version 12.4.